# Include dando espaçamento

Tags: php, css

estou com problema em `<?php echo include_once ("includes/right.php");?>` ele da uma `margin-top` indesejavel, como eu poderia resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Quais os códigos da página atual e a da que está sendo incluída?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove o `echo`. Não sei porque razão ele está ai. Para incluir um ficheiro basta `<?php include_once("caminho/para/o/ficheiro.php");?>`.

**EDIT**
Código que falei no comentário.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <ul>
            <li><div class="box_left">
                <h1>Entre em Contato</h1>

            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right"><?phpinclude ("includes/right.php"); ?></div>

    <?php 
        include_once ("includes/footer.php");
    ?>
</div><!-- content -->
```

Comment: Desculpa amigo, mais não tem `echo`, apenas o `<?php include_once("includes/right.php");?>`

Comment: Entao ele da um espaço porque tambem tem um espaço no código html. Coloca assim.

Comment: Olha como está o código na parte que esta dando a `margin-top`  `<div id="right">
   <?php 
    include ("includes/right.php");
   ?>
  </div>`

Comment: Fiz update da resposta. Tenta isso.

Comment: mesma coisa, confere no link do meu site https://caminhocomjesuscristo.000webhostapp.com/new2/

Comment: não resolveu o problema amigo, confere no link  https://caminhocomjesuscristo.000webhostapp.com/new2/

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando na codificação `UTF-8 sem BOM` grato pela atenção amigo